# OmniPascal installed in VSCode - Delphi file extensions broken

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-code, omnipascal

First StackOverflow question ever.

Just installed OmniPascal extension into VSCode. Now ".dproj" and ".dpr" files are no longer associated with Embarcadero Delphi.

This seems non-trivial to fix. Can anyone suggest a fix short of reinstalling Embarcadero?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should to read tutorial "How to use OS Windows" before start programming

Comment: This **is** trivial. See http://superuser.com/questions/621366/how-to-associate-i01-microstation-file-with-ustation-exe-in-windows-7

Comment: Repair install of Delphi would fix this I believe, and in the most robust way

Comment: Just to clarify it:The OmniPascal extension doesn't change Windows' file type associations. Anything else broke it on your system.

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click on any `.dproj` or `.dpr` files
2. Select **Open with...** and then click **Choose default program**
3. Find and choose **bds.exe**(Embarcadero Rad Studio)
4. Selec the **Always use the selected program to open this kind of file** check box, and then click **OK**.

See [Change the program that opens a type of file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: FWIW: Delphi installs a launcher program: On my system *.dpr is associated with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Bin\bdsLauncher.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Bin\bds.exe" /np`.

Comment: @MegaTron: My bad. I had done what you suggest before posting, which I should of course have mentioned (along with mentioning I was using 10.1 Berlin) to avoid sarcasm.  I will try a repair or reinstall - the two-hour process is what I was hoping to avoid.